# mobx state tree as module in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mobx

I cannot export mobx model as module.
I found some advice but I dont know how to do it.

```
import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree'

export default types.model('Test')
```

> [ts] Default export of the module has or is using private name 'IModelType'.

or

```
const model = types.model('Login')
export default model
```

> [ts] Exported variable 'model' has or is using name 'IModelType' from external module "..." but cannot be named.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `"declaration": true` in your `tsconfig.json` and you need to explicitly export `IModelType` so that the consumer of your library have the appropriate typings.

Either add

```
export { IModelType } from 'mobx-state-tree'
```

to this source file or set `"declaration": false` in your `tsconfig.json` if you're not publishing your library.